# How to delete one list from the other list that removes the element just once

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to delete one list from the other list that removes the element just once. like following example:

```
list1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
list2= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output=[6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

I used set, but it removes all the elements that are in one list form the other list

```
set(list1)-set(list2)
output= {6, 7}
```

Comment: So you want to remove the first found item of `list1` for each item in `list2`?

Comment: yes, may be first found item is a correct word for that

Answer (score 1):

You first want a collection of unique elements (set) to choose which to remove in the list. Then, iterate through the collection of unique elements one at a time and remove one instance of the element from the list, until you have no more unique elements in the collection.

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
se = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9} # 9 is intentionally added to show error handling

for element in se:
    try:
        li.remove(element)
    except ValueError:
        print("Element '%s' doesn't exist in the list." % element)

print(li) # prints: [6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

It's important to note that `list.remove()` raises a `ValueError` should an attempt to remove a non-existent item occur. One approach (the more pythonic approach) is to have a try-except block catch the error. You can choose how you wish to handle the error; I just chose to print out an error message. The other approach is to have a defensive test. Here's the if-else for defensive coding:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
se = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

for element in se:
    if element in li:
        li.remove(element)

print(li) # prints: [6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

one liner exploiting side effect
the list comprehension output is not the list you want - but it is modifying `list1` as it works

```
list1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
list2= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


[list1.pop(list1.index(e)) for e in list2 if e in list1]
Out[65]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

list1
Out[66]: [6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

it would look better if you also needed the list comprehension output of removed items, otherwise someone might think you had abused the list comprehension when you should have just written a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the second list and delete the element from the first list if it is found. Here is a sample code:

```
for element in l2:
 if element in l1:
  index = l1.index(element)
  del l1[index]
```

Edit: see input/output from command line.

Input:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l2 = [2, 3, 5, 6]
>>> for element in l2:
...  if element in l1:
...   index = l1.index(element)
...   del l1[index]
...
```

Output:

```
>>> l1
[1, 4]
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I have edited my answer with the input/output from the command line which shows you that it gives you the difference between the two lists. Based on your code, you need to replace the list names in my code by list1 and list2.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the two lists, you need to look at the problem with reference to list2.  Since you want to delete each duplicate, you can iterate over list2 and remove each duplicate entry in list1 as they are found in reference to list2.

```
list1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]
list2= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output=[6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5]

for i in list2:
    try: del list1[list1.index(i)]
    except ValueError: pass
```

This way if an item is in list2 it is deleted from list1 as many times as it occurs in list2 and if there are more occurrences of one item in the second list than the first, the error is caught.